# How to perform Source Code Scanning on a code that is using RSA Key Container

Tags: security, scanning, penetration-testing, source-code-protection, sast

I am trying to peform a source code scan on a c# source code that was shared to me by the appication team. When I was feeding this code to tool it said build failed. I followed up with the applicaion team to ensure no dependencies were missed when sharing the code to me.

I succesfully imported the key container and used aspnet_regiis.exe to decrypt. Now, my doubt is If I upload this code to any tool and scan will this work since I have provided my userid and since I have provided access to RSA key container. Note that, the tool is a shared instance and not installed in my machine. IF not, what is the best way I can scan this code for vulnerabilities